# How to call a JavaScript function from Select Option with Html

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I need to call a javascript fuction when the user select 2 options : Refusé and Activé

so I did this but it doesn't work

edit : I don't get any errors but after choosing `Activé` or `Refusé` the span and the checkbox don't show up the function `Visibility` isn't called**

```
<body onload="hidecheckbox()">    

 <script>
    function hidecheckbox() {
        document.getElementById("checkbox").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    </script>
  

 <div>
    <span >Etat de la candidature</span>
    <select name="etat">
       <option  value="En cours">En cours de traitement</option>
       <option onclick="Visibility()" value="Accepté">Accepté</option>
      <option onclick="Visibility()" value="Refusé">Refusé</option>                                    
   </select>
</div>                   
<div id="checkbox" >
   <span>Envoyer un email automatique </span>
   <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" value="Envoyer un email automatique">
</div>
           
<script>
function Visibility() 
{                  
   document.getElementById("checkbox").style.visibility = "visible";
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: extra space in `< div>`

Comment: Where is `hidecheckbox` used? [What Do You Mean “It Doesn’t Work”?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616/289905) Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mre], along with your _desired_ results, your _actual_ results, including all _errors_, and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. The dev tools provide an **Inspector** / **Elements**. Use it to your advantage. Please [validate your HTML](//html5.validator.nu/).

Comment: Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [not recommended](/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

Comment: ```document.getElementsByTagName("etat").addEventListener("change", hideCheckbox);```

Comment: @akhilrawat001 i did it because when I first wrote `<div>` it didn't show up so I added a space. Anyway is that your answer to my question or do you have an other one solution to help me please

Comment: @esQmo_ What about this line of code? This will result in a TypeError.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I don't get an error but the span and checkbox don't show up after choosing `activé` or `refusé`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use onChange event on the select

```
<select name="etat" id="mySel" onChange="Visibility()">
  <option value="En cours">En cours de traitement</option>
  <option value="Accepté">Accepté</option>
  <option value="Refusé">Refusé</option>
</select>
```

and then change the Javascript

```
function Visibility() {
  var sel = document.getElementById("mySel").value;
  /* Use the above value of select option */
  document.getElementById("checkbox").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this would be adding `onchange` to select. Also, you can pass `this` as parameter to get the target inside the function. Something like this should be fine:

```
   <select name="etat" onchange="Visibility(this)">
       <option value="Accepté">Accepté</option>
      <option value="Refusé">Refusé</option>                    
   </select>
```

You can then access the option selected using the `value` attribute like this:

```
function Visibility(e) 
{                  
  console.log(e.value)
   document.getElementById("checkbox").style.visibility = "visible";
 }
```

Comment: The _recommended_ way would be `document.querySelector("select[name='etat']").addEventListener("change", () => document.getElementById("checkbox").style.visibility = "visible");`. Don’t suggest `onchange` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

The onclick attribute on `<option>` tag does not work. Instead you can use an onChange attribute on the `<select>` tag. Here is how it would work.

```
  <select id="select" name="etat" onChange="Visibility()">
    <option value="En cours">En cours de traitement</option>
    <option value="Accepté">Accepté</option>
    <option value="Refusé">Refusé</option>
  </select>
```

And then inside your Visibility function.

```
function Visibility() {
  let option = document.getElementById("select").value;

  if (option === "Accepté" || option === "Refusé") {
    // If you selected Accepté or Refusé show the checkbox
    document.getElementById("checkbox").style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    // If you selected En cours de traitement hide the checkbox
    document.getElementById("checkbox").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/fmo2drwx/ I have renamed some elements.

```
<script>
function hideCheckbox() {
  document.getElementById("checkbox").style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function changeVisibility() {
  document.getElementById("checkbox").style.visibility = "visible";
}</script>
<div>
  <span>Etat de la candidature</span>
  <select name="etat">
    <option value="En cours">En cours de traitement</option>
    <option onClick="changeVisibility()" value="Accepté">Accepté</option>
    <option onClick="changeVisibility()" value="Refusé">Refusé</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="checkbox" style="visibility: hidden;">
  <span>Envoyer un email automatique </span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check"  value="Envoyer un email automatique">
</div>
```